# How can I self close the browser in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a simple `html` page with `javascript` which auto-closes itself after opening.

My main aim is that I want to redirect the user to this page after some data update in the popup window so that windows gets closed after the data is updated.

I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: you want to close a popup window after doing something?

Comment: `I am not able to figure it out.`   likely find it in google faster than creating this question

Comment: i tried window.close before and it didn't worked , i thought i was doing wrong. then i realised there was some script error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JSFiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/XaSKY/ to see in action.

You can use `window.close()` function